# while display listview.builder from firestore flutter using streambuilder, got an error,?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

while display listview.builder from firestore flutter using streambuilder, got an error,?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llDpO.png

Comment: the error is :
 The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

Comment: please share with screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `documents` use [`data()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) because `DocumentSnapshot` doesn't have a property called `documents`.

Also make sure to check `snapshot.hasData` in the `builder`.

Comment: could you post the code related to `userStrem`?